# auto update/insert join-table field when adding objects to self-referential rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

first post on SO, woohoo!  RoR did it :)  there's quite a bit on SO and even in the RoR guides that get really close, but don't quite address what I want to do.

I want to model an ingredient, where each ingredient may also have an ordered list of sub-ingredients - the (summarized) msyql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `ingredients`
  id
  name

CREATE TABLE `composite_ingredients`
  parent_id
  composite_id
  sort_order int
  CONSTRAINT `fk_one` FOREIGN KEY (`composite_id`) REFERENCES `ingredients` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_two` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `ingredients` (`id`)
```

and here's how I'm modeling so far

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

    has_many :composites, :class_name=>"CompositeIngredient",
                          :foreign_key=>'parent_id'

    has_many :sorted_composites, :through=>:composites, 
                                 :source=>:composite, 
                                 :class_name=>'Ingredient', 
                                 :order=>'sort_order asc'

class CompositeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :sort_order

    belongs_to :parent, :class_name=>'Ingredient', 
                        :foreign_key=>'parent_id'

    belongs_to :composite, :class_name=>'Ingredient', 
                           :foreign_key=>'composite_id'
```

While testing in the rails console, I'm able to successfully play around with this a bit:

```
a=Ingredient.includes(:sorted_composites).first
b=Ingredient.find_by_name 'corn'
a.sorted_composites<<b
```

That's all working fine - now 'a' will have 'b' correctly associated with it (ie: there's a record in the join table composite_ingredients.)  However, the sort_order field is in the CompositeIngredient objects, which are hanging out in a.composites (whereas i have actual Ingredient objects in a.sorted_composites.)  When I add ingredients to a.sorted_composites, i want to set the sort_order before inserting into the join table ... does that make sense?  I basically wanna accomplish this:

```
a.composites.create :parent_id=>a.id, composite_id=>b.id, sort_order=>a.sorted_composites.size
```

when i do this

```
a.sorted_composites << b
```

Once I accomplish that, the :order option to my has_many will take care of the ordering of the sortd_composites when they're coming out of the DB - it's going INTO the join table I need to wire in.

Thanks everybody!

**EDIT:**
The reason for the sort order: there's implicit value in the order that a composite ingredient appears - those that sort to the front of the list are a more "abundant" component of their parent.  For example, if parent ingredient X has composites Y and Z in that order, then Y is more abundant in X than Z.

**EDIT:**
After playing around some more, this seems to be the most meaningful solution I've been able to come up with:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name

    has_many :composites, :class_name=>"CompositeIngredient",
                          :foreign_key=>'parent_id',
                          **:before_add=>:before_composite_add**
    ...
    def before_composite_add(new_composite)
        new_composite.sort_order = self.sorted_composites.size
    end
```

Though being a total RoR noob, I welcome any feedback/criticism/suggestions.

Comment: Can you do this? a.sorted_composites.create(:composite => b, sort_order => a.composites.size)

Comment: Can you give more context on what you're using the `sort_order` for? I am finding it hard to understand how you're having trouble with it

Comment: @swards, i get this error: ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: composite, sort_order.

Comment: @Rich, I'll update the post momentarily to include a little more info

Comment: You'll need attr_accessible on the model - attr_accessible :composite, :sort_order.  This is to make sure you explicitly allow attrbitutes to be mass assigned.

Comment: @swards hmm, i may not understand - am i adding attr_accessible on CompositeIngredient?  that doesn't make sense if I'm doing a.sorted_composites.create ...?  sorted_composites is a list of Ingredient objects, which do not have a notion of :composite or :sort_order (those are both on the join object/table.)

Comment: It would be on Ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

I've left a comment for clarification, and I felt it best to give you some further ideas as to how it might work:

> Your current setup relies on having `ingredients`, which can then be
>   associated using the `composite_ingredients` join model. It looks like
>   `composite_ingredients` is a self-referential `has_many :through` join
>   model, which could be a little rigid (what if you wanted to change the structure in future)

Why don't you just put them all in the same model using the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)? This will allow you to create a column called `parent`, which the gem will populate. This will allow you to associate any ingredient with `child` ingredients without a join model:

```
@ingredient.children #-> all decendents of node
```

This will allow you to do away with the join model, giving you the ability to keep the `sort_order` for each ingredient / child ingredient, instead of splitting into join model

Comment: unfortunately this won't work :(  an ingredient can be a composite of more than 1 parent, so it won't suffice to have a single parent ID column for a give ingredient.  additionally, an ingredient may appear in varying sort-positions when it is the composite of a parent, and so the sort-order is also crucial.  that's a neat gem though!